# How to detect a transform-only UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

`UIStackView` is a transform-only view.  This means it is not possible to perform operations on the view's layer.

Is there a general-case way to detect if a `UIView` is a transform-only view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Actually, transform-only view is view which has `CATransformLayer` layer.

So the question should be `How to detect a UIView which has transform-only layer?` and the answer is very simple, check class's type of `view.layer`.

For example, when you want to change `cornerRadius` on `stackView.layer`, it will through a warning like

> changing property cornerRadius in transform-only layer, will have no effect

It's not because something which is called `transform-only view`, it's because you are changing `cornerRadius` on a `CATransformLayer` and `cornerRadius` property is ignored according to [Apple document for CATransformLayer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/catransformlayer).

> Only the sublayers of a transform layer are rendered. The CALayer properties that are rendered by a layer are ignored, including: backgroundColor, contents, border style properties, stroke style properties, etc.

Something you maybe wrong is *It's possible to perform operations on the view's layer but not all of them.*

How to detect if a `UIView` is a transform-only view? - Use below extension

```
extension UIView {
  func isTransformOnlyView() -> Bool {
    return self.layer.isKind(of: CATransformLayer.self)
  }
}
```

Usage

```
stackView.isTransformOnlyView()
```